# I tried to do a password system. but I couldn' t get entry from user, can someone explain me why?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, passwords

When I write the informations into input sections and click to button, the program printing [] part no matter if infos match with the true conditions. I think my "def" function or .get() system is wrong but I couldn't find any correct way on the net.

```
from os import defpath
from tkinter import *
#from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

username = ["Enes"]
age = ["19"]
password = ["Bruh"]

username_g = []
age_g = []
passwork_g = []

response = Entry(root)
response.pack()

response2 = Entry(root)
response2.pack()

response4 = Entry(root)
response4.pack()

def loginbruh():
   #response.get()
   #response2.get()
   #response3.get()
   #response4.get()
    username_g + [response.get()]
    age_g + [response2.get()]
    password_g + [response4.get()]


   if password_g == password and age_g == age and username_g == username:
      print("Doğru girdiniz")
   else:
      print(password_g)


login_button = Button(root, text="Login", command=loginbruh)
login_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you think happens when you run: `username_g + [response.get()]`? Is the result stored somewhere? Also your logic behind that if statement is flawed. Shouldn't you have `root.mainloop()` at the end of your code? When you use `response2.get()`, it will be a `str` but your `age_g` variable uses `int`s

Comment: Why are you storing those as lists

Comment: TheLizzard, I am listing them beacuse I couldn't do it otherwise so I tried to use a list to compare in if part. Also sorry, I wrote the main.loop() right now, it was in the main code but I forgot to copy it. Also I changed 19 into str but nothing happens.

Comment: @Nsdmr.x When you use `username_g + [response.get()]`, the result isn't stored in `username_g`. It is the same as doing: `a = 1` then `a + 1` and `print(a)`. The result will be 1 because the result of `a + 1` isn't stored in `a`

Comment: @TheLizzard thx for the info bro, but can u tell me how can I get entry from entry widget and compare it with the username?

Comment: Just remove the lists and simply compare.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thx guys! I removed all the lists and it is working right now, I cant believe I just wasted my 2 days with this... thx a lot!

Comment: @Dharman okay bro, sorry I am new to this website. I did it and turned the code to it's first release.

Answer (score 1):

I remove the lists and directly used .get(), it worked!

```
from os import defpath
from tkinter import *
#from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

username = "Enes"
age = "19"
password = "Bruh"


response = Entry(root)
response.pack()

response2 = Entry(root)
response2.pack()

response4 = Entry(root)
response4.pack()

def loginbruh():
   #response.get()
   #response2.get()
   #response3.get()
   #response4.get()
    
    


   if response4.get() == password and str(response2.get()) == age and response.get() == username:
      print("Doğru girdiniz")
   else:
      print(response.get())


login_button = Button(root, text="Login", command=loginbruh)
login_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```